# KDbg - how to dock the memory window into the main Kdbg window?

Tags: kdbg

OS: Kubuntu 10.10
KDbg version: 2.2.1

I am using KDbg 2.2.1 on Kubuntu 10.10. I installed it from one of the standard repositories (i.e. "sudo apt-get install kdbg"). What I need help with is, how do I dock the separate memory window into the main application window? I've tried to drag it over to the main window, but that does not work. Since I use the memory window pretty often, I want it to be part of the main window along with the stack, output and watch windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@daihard there are dotted lines on the seperate windows, if you grab it with the mouse and drag it into the main window it will let you place it.

Jim

Comment: Thank you so much, Jim! Worked perfectly.

Dai